# Solve $2\sqrt y\ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Using reduction of order method solve
$$2\sqrt y\ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2=0$$ given initial conditions $y=1$, $\frac{dy}{dx}=e^{-1}$ at $x=0$. Express your answer in the form $x=x(y)$.

So far I have let $p=\frac {dy} {dx}$ and subbed into ODE, then I rearranged and used separation of variables and got to a line which says

$$x = 2A \sqrt y {\rm e}^{\sqrt y} - 2A {\rm e}^{\sqrt y} + Ac$$

where $A$ and $c$ are constants of integration. How do I get this into general form and is this correct? Thanks.

Comment: Some effort on your part would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey, sorry this does look bad on my half. But I posted this question for a friend. I don't know differential equations myself so thought this would be a good way to give her a helping hand.

Comment: Then your friend ought to show some effort on their part. "I posted a low quality question for a friend" is no better than just posting the question.

Comment: I will try my best to explain to where she has got to. She let p=dy/dx and subbed into ODE. Then rearranged and used separation of variables and got to a line which says x=2*A*sqrt(y)*e^(sqrt(y))-2*A*e^(sqrt(y))+Ac where A and c are constants of integration. Now she is struggling to put this into the general form of an ODE.

Comment: Does this suffice? Apologise again I do see how bad this might look but was not intended to get a "free answer" more a helping hand.

Comment: I'm not going to be as critical as the others, but perhaps your friend should post herself.  This is open to the public and pretty easy to post to.  Latex is a pain in the assignment but otherwise...

Answer (score 1):

Divide by $\sqrt yy'$ to get

$$2\frac{y''}{y'}+\frac{y'}{\sqrt y}=0.$$

You can integrate and simplify by $2$, giving

$$\ln(y')+\sqrt y=C,$$ i.e.

$$e^{\sqrt y}y'=C'.$$

Integrating again,

$$C'x+C''=\int e^{\sqrt y}dy=2(\sqrt y-1)e^{\sqrt y}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{hint}$
$$
\ddot{y} = \dot{y}\frac{d}{dy} \dot{y}
$$
Make the sub $\dot{y} = p$ resolve.

Comment: I was hoping for more of a fully worked solution. Thanks

Comment: @MathsNoob We were hoping for more than a PSQ with orders given. Thanks.